grpc-java running in a docker container oom
grpc:1.65.1
dockerVersion:18.09.0
baseDockerImage: azul/zulu-openjdk:17-latest
Here is a simple interface that receives a byte array and then directly returns the data. During stress testing, using 10KB size data works fine, but using 1MB size data causes an OOM (Out of Memory) exception. I have specified the direct memory limit to 2GB at startup using -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G, but the OOM issue still occurs.
exception:
2024-08-02 10:40:04.375 [grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-14] INFO  i.g.n.N.connections - Transport failed
io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 2097152 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 534774039, max: 536870912)
at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:845)
at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:774)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:721)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:696)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:215)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateSmall(PoolArena.java:180)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:137)
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:129)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:396)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:140)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:120)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:150)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
1.I replaced the original OpenJDK8 with JDK17 and enabled ZGC.
2.I set the DirectMemory to 2GB using -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G.
3.I called request.toBuilder().clear().build() at the end of the method.
